# Error: Could not find or load main class com.mongo.application.MongoApplication

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data

Error is occurring in open of `<parent>` in `pom.xml`

```
package com.mongo.application;     
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableMongoRepositories("com.mongo.repository")

public class MongoApplication {    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MongoApplication.class, args);
    }

    public void run() {
    }
}
```

OUTPUT:

> ERROR:  Could not find or load main class `com.mongo.application.MongoApplication`

Comment: Please introduce the problem and tell us what you have tried so far. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for tips.

Comment: What does "Error is occurring in open of <parent> in pom.xml" mean? What are you doing that results in the error mentioned?

Comment: please show you pom.xml.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the following which resolved the issues.

1. Deleting .metadata file in eclipse workspace
2. Opening the ecilpse after this and importing the project
3. I noticed some of the jar files in my maven dependencies were corrupt as was displaced in problems tab which is next to console tab.
4. So went to the Jar location and Deleted the same.
5. then Clicked alt+f5 to force update the maven project so it can download the same again.

Finally My Issues got Resolved.
Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

your Maven local repository will be corrupted,
So just delete the hidden .m2 folder completely and restart your project
it will solve tour problem.